# Video.js Chapter Button Not Clickable sometimes on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mobile, video.js

I'm facing an issue with my Video.js implementation where the chapter button is not consistently clickable on mobile devices. When I tap the chapter button on some mobile devices, it doesn't respond as expected. I've provided the relevant code snippet below for reference.

I have a Video.js player with a custom chapter button that reveals a list of chapters when clicked.
The issue is primarily observed on mobile devices (touch interactions).
Sometimes, tapping the chapter button doesn't trigger the expected behavior (showing the chapter list).
I'm using Video.js version ["video.js": "^8.3.0",
"videojs-playlist": "^5.1.0",
"videojs-playlist-ui": "^4.2.1"] in a React application.
The chapter button works fine on desktop mode  browsers.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (videoRef.current && options != null) {
      // Initialize Video.js player
      player = videojs(videoRef.current, {
        ...options,
        autoplay: true, // Enable autoplay
        fluid: true,
        muted: mute ? true : false,
        controls: hideControl ? false : true,
        preload: true,
        playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],
        controlBar: {
          ...options.controlBar,
          skipButtons: {
            backward: 5,
            forward: 5
          },
          volumePanel: { inline: false },
          fullscreenToggle: true, // Enable fullscreen button
        },
      });

      setPlayerRef(player)

      player.ready(() => {
        player.playlist(options)
        if (options.length > 1) {
            const chapterButton = player.controlBar.addChild('button', {
              height: 20,
              name: 'chapter',
              className: 'chapter'
            }, 12)
            const chapterButtonDom = chapterButton.el();
            chapterButtonDom.innerHTML = `<span class="vjs-icon-chapters"></span> `
            chapterButton.on('click',function(){
               console.log('chapter button clicked')
              setIsListShow(prevIsListShow => !prevIsListShow);
              console.log(istListShow)
  
            })
           
           
          console.log('set', istListShow)
          const nextButton = player.controlBar.addChild('button', {
            height: 20,
            name: 'next',
            className: 'nextButton'
          }, 12)
          setNextBtn(nextButton)
          const nextButtonDom = nextButton.el();
          nextButtonDom.innerHTML = '<span class="vjs-icon-next-item"></span>'
          nextButtonDom.onclick = function () {
            const id = window.location.search.replaceAll('?cid=', '');
            const index = options.findIndex((item: any) => item.id === id);
            if (index + 1 < options.length) {
              const newId = options[index + 1].id;
              onEpisodeClick(newId, index + 1)
            }

            return null;
          }
        }

        const videoTitleText = player.controlBar.addChild('button', {
          name: 'videoName',
          className: 'videoTitleBottom'
        }, 12)
        const videoTitleDom = videoTitleText.el();
        // videoTitleDom.innerHTML = options[player?.playlist?.currentItem()]?.name
        // videoTitleDom.innerHTML = options[0].name
        let name = options[0].name
        assignTitle(name)

        if (!hideControl) player.aspectRatio('16:8');

        // player.fill(true)
        player.responsive(true)
        if (videoRef.current && !hideControl) {
          const id = window.location.search.replaceAll('?cid=', '');
          const index = options.findIndex((item: any) => item.id === id);
          if (index != -1) {
            videoRef.current.currentTime = options[index].watchedDuration;
          }
        }

        // player.playlistUi();
      });

      player.on("waiting", function () {
        player.addClass('vjs-seeking')
      });
      player.on("playing", function () {
        player.removeClass('vjs-seeking')
      });

      player.on("pause", function () {
        setTitleOverCurrentItem(player?.playlist?.currentItem())
        setTimeout(() => { setShowDetailOnOverlay(true) }, 10000)
        var timerId: any = 0
        document.addEventListener("click", function () {
          clearTimeout(timerId);
          setShowDetailOnOverlay(false)
          timerId = setTimeout(function () {
            setShowDetailOnOverlay(true)
          }, 10000);
        });

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
          clearTimeout(timerId);
          setShowDetailOnOverlay(false)
          timerId = setTimeout(function () {
            setShowDetailOnOverlay(true)
          }, 10000);
        });
      });


      player.on("play", function () {
        mute = false;
        setShowDetailOnOverlay(false)
      });

      player.on("ended", () => {
        player.playlist.next();
        let currentIndex = player?.playlist.currentItem();
        if (currentIndex <= options.length) {
          let currentId = options[currentIndex].id;
          onEpisodeClick(currentId, currentIndex);
        }

      });
      // Destroy Video.js player on component unmount
      return () => {
        if (player) {
          player.dispose();
          player = null;
        }
      };
    }
  }, []);



//this one for mobile version
useEffect(() => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 640) {
      if (videoRef.current && options != null) {
        // Initialize Video.js player
        const playerInstance = videojs(videoRef.current, options, () => {
          setPlayers(playerInstance);
            const chapterButton = player.controlBar.addChild('button', {
              height: 20,
              name: 'chapterButtons',
              className: 'chapterButtons'
            }, 12)
            const chapterButtonDom = chapterButton.el();
            chapterButtonDom.innerHTML = ` <span class="chapter-button-content" >&#171;</span>`
            chapterButtonDom.onclick = function () {
              console.log('chapter button clicked')
              setIsListShow(prevIsListShow => !prevIsListShow);
              console.log(istListShow)
  
            };
            chapterButton.hide()
            player.on('fullscreenchange', () => {
            if(player.isFullscreen()&& window.innerWidth<640){
              chapterButton.show()
            }else{
              chapterButton.hide()
            }
            })
          
          playerInstance.on("fullscreenchange", () => {
            const controlbarCol = document.querySelector(".vjs-control-bar");
            if (playerInstance.isFullscreen()) {
              if (controlbarCol) {
                controlbarCol.classList.add("videoFullScreen")
              }} else {
              if (controlbarCol) {
                controlbarCol.classList.remove("videoFullScreen")
              }
             
            }

          });
        });
      }
    }
  }, [options]);
```

Comment: i fixed this issue by addind 'touchstart' event for mobile instead of 'click ' event . my suggestion is that always use 'touchstart' event for mobile in video js